# Highcharts - SMA Indicator does not display

Tags: highcharts

Good evening.

I can not see the SMA indicators on my Highcharts after emitting an event depending on which period was selected from a select menu. Here is my select element:

```
  <select id="chartIndicatorSelect" onchange="setIndicator(this)">   
       <option value='{"id": null}'>#{msg.chart_indicator_nothing}</option>      
       <option value='{"id":"sma", "linkedTo":"prices", "name":"Simple Moving Average","type":"sma", "params":{"period":3}, "color": "5555aa", "yAxis":0}'>#{msg.chart_indicator_sma_3}</option>
       <option value='{"id":"sma", "linkedTo":"prices", "name":"Simple Moving Average","type":"sma", "params":{"period":18}, "color": "fabbbf", "yAxis":0}'>#{msg.chart_indicator_sma_18}</option>
       <option value='{"id":"sma", "linkedTo":"prices", "name":"Simple Moving Average","type":"sma", "params":{"period":38}, "color": "f4777d", "yAxis":0}'>#{msg.chart_indicator_sma_38}</option>
       <option value='{"id":"sma", "linkedTo":"prices", "name":"Simple Moving Average","type":"sma", "params":{"period":90}, "color": "d41923", "yAxis":0}'>#{msg.chart_indicator_sma_90}</option>
       <option value='{"id":"sma", "linkedTo":"prices", "name":"Simple Moving Average","type":"sma", "params":{"period":200}, "color": "a1131a", "yAxis":0}'>#{msg.chart_indicator_sma_200}</option>
    </select>
```

And here is my setIndicator():

```
            function setIndicator(indicator){
                let indicatorValue = jQuery.parseJSON(indicator.value);             
                window.interactiveChart.$emit("mobileIndicatorEventTrigger", {'indicator':indicatorValue})
            }
```

in my VUE app where I render my Highcharts, I parse the data correctly and I push it into the series as it is supposed to be:

[image]

but still my chart is not displaying it. The main series id is prices. I also make sure to redraw the chart. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, could you recreate your case at online code editor? Here is template that you can use: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-qkf43

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Just noticed I did not use hashtag in the color string so the color would not be parsed correctly!!